# why different results in (tikz graph) output while compiling same code?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to replicate the first basic example on graphs in the Tikz-Pgfplots manual (pg no. 258) [image]

However, try to compile the two MWE's below one by one. In one, the pdf fails to compile (with 30 errors!) (mostly to do with some csname)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\verteq}{\rotatebox{90}{$\,\neq$}}
\newcommand{\equalto}[2]{\underset{\scriptstyle\overset{\mkern4mu\verteq}{#2}}{#1}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{document}



\tikz \graph { a -> {b, c} -> d };

\end{document}
```

In the MWE below, I have a strange output

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}

\tikz \graph { a -> {b, c} -> d };

\end{document}
```

With the following output:

[image: Output of example 2]

Why am I not getting the desired output in both cases. It seems that some other package is interfering in the first example. How should one go about in finding out the error in such cases?

Comment: Are you using the right version of TikZ (3.0)? Are you compiling the document using `lualatex`? What error messages do you get?

Comment: @Jake: Thanks. I just load TikZ using the `\usepackage` command. How to check the version, please? Yes, I tried both latex and lualatex, the error remains. The error messages I get: Extra endcsname, missing endcsname inserted, package pgf error. No shape named \tikz@lg3 known

Comment: Note that there is no error displayed in the second example. The output is wrong, though

Comment: Take a look at the `.log` file, it'll mention the TikZ version

Comment: It says "Package: tikz 2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)", seems like we are onto something

Comment: Yes, that version doesn't include the required functionality. You'll have to upgrade.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15030/discussion-between-abhimanyu-arora-and-jake).

Comment: You need TikZ version 3.00 and compile it via LuaLaTeX. Your reported version doesn't have the graph drawing library

Comment: @percusse: Thanks very much. Yes, there seems to be some updating error. Trying to update MikTeX

Comment: The problem is even as I try to update the MikTeX distribution and the package manager shows the newest version of `pgf`, when I compile the .tex file, the errors still remain and the log file shows the old tikz version. Bizarre

Comment: Did you use the "standard" MikTeX updater or the "Admin" variant? Depending on how `pgf` was originally installed, you may need to use the other.

Comment: @PaulGessler: Thanks for the tip. I used both for package manager and the update wizard. But I guess I might have to ask the admin to synchronize as well. Else I will install TexLive on a non-C drive where I wouldn't need admin privileges for updates

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is trying to use features of a version of TikZ more recent than the one available on his/her system